# MAX IF INDEX Function?

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing

Currently, I have a table like the one below.

```
               Jan-16   Feb-16  Mar-16  Apr-16  May-16  Jun-16  Jul-16  Aug-16  Sep-16  Oct-16  Nov-16  Dec-16
Forecast       5        8       7       -       -       -       -       -       -       -       -       -
```

The monthly forecast figure is set to populate only once that month closes.

In my dashboard, I am attempting to capture the most recent Forecast number in this table so the output would look something like...

```
Current Forecast    7
```

I would assume that to achieve this, Current Forecast would require a series of IF, INDEX, MATCH, and MAX (for max date) functions but I'm unable to figure this out.

**From deleted comments:**

Sorry I didn't clarify. That's correct-- the "-" are zeros with the number format applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question would be if those are real dates across row 1 or text-that-look-like-dates. Let's say those are real dates formatted as *mmm-yy* because that is the better method.

The second question is whether the inactive numbers in row 2 are showing hyphens because they are zeroes with an accounting style number format or if you have actually put hyphens in the cells. Let's say they are zeroes with an accounting style number format because that is the better way to do it.

```
=INDEX(B2:M2, MATCH(AGGREGATE(14, 6, (B1:M1)/(B2:M2<>0), 1), B1:M1, 0))
' for pre xl2010 systems w/o AGGREGATE
=INDEX(B2:M2, MATCH(MAX(INDEX((B1:M1)+(B2:M2=0)*-1E+99, , )), B1:M1, 0))
```

[image: maxif_aggregate]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but looks like it'll do what you're looking for.

```
=INDEX(B$2:M$2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:M2<>"-",),0))
```

[Modified from here](https://superuser.com/questions/671435/excel-formula-to-get-first-non-zero-value-in-row-and-return-column-header)

As Dirk pointed out, this actually returns the first match.

Comment: First `'-'` should be `"-"` and secondly returns your formula the **first** value and not the last one. It looks like you tried something like `=INDEX(B$2:M$2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:M2="-",),0)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

if there are no empty dates between the values then, then this formula will do:

```
=INDEX(B2:M2,COUNTIF(B2:M2,"<>-"))
```

and having empty dates inbetween then this array-formula will do

```
=INDEX(B2:M2,MAX(ISNUMBER(B2:M2)*COLUMN(A:L)))
```

> Needs to be confirmed with Ctrl + Shift + Enter